# Model to compare the methods with 0/1 outcome

Tags: model

I have all in all 600 measurements: 20 subjects x 15 different stimuli x 2 ears (presented in each ear separately). I use 4 different methods to detect whether there is a significant response in each measurement. The output of each method is either 0 (not significant) or 1 (significant). I need to test which method gives me the most number of significant detections. I also use different amount of data (10-20-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100 % of the measurement time) for each method to find out how fast the methods can detect the significant response, i.e. which method is more effective.

I am not interested how the methods perform for each individual stimulus, but how they perform in general.

Please help me to find the correct model to compare the methods!

Best regards
Anna

Comment: "I need to test which method gives me the most number of significant detections" - why not just count which method gives you the most number of significant detections?

Comment: yes, I can do that, and already did, but I need to know is there statistically significant difference between methods or not. Some of the methods are computationally heavy, but they give for example 12 more, so I need to know if it is worth to use these methods.